# How should t_Co be being set?

Tags: macos, vim, iterm

I am on OS X 10.6.2 and am using iTerm as my terminal.  When I run Vim, `t_Co` gets set to `8`.  I want it to be `16` or `256` if I can display that many colors.  If I manually set `t_Co` to be 16 (i.e. `:se t_Co=16` or `set t_Co=16` in `.vimrc`) everything works fine.

Why doesn't `t_Co` get set to the highest available number?  Is there some option I should be setting in iTerm or some environment variable I should be setting to make termcap pass the right information to `vim`?  Is it safe to just override `t_Co` in my `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going into Bookmarks->Manage Bookmarks..., expanding Terminal Profiles, choosing Default, and setting Type to be xterm-256color in the drop-down listbox causes `t_Co` to be 256.

Answer (score 0):

iTerm 2 makes this a lot easier to do, and is actively supported. I recommend trying http://code.google.com/p/iterm2

Comment: Yeah, I switched over about a month ago.  I need to take a look at the new release it is bugging me about.